# Finding event with constant probability regardless of $ p $ in case of Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $ \{ X _ i \} _ { i \in \mathbb N } $ be independent Bernoulli random variables with a parameter for $ 0 < p < 1 $. Find a single event $ A $ that has a probability of $ \frac 1 2 $ regardless of the value of $ p $ and a second event $ B $ that always has a probability of $ \frac 1 3 $. Use the $ \sigma $-algebra axioms to show that $ A $ and $ B $ are actually events.
> (Hint: The function $ f ( x _ 0 , x _ 1 , \dots ) = ( x _ 1 , x _ 0 , x _ 3 , x _ 2 , \dots ) $ preserves probabilities and $ f \big( f ( x ) \big) = x $.)

I don't know how to even begin solving this question. I don't even understand how the hint will help. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For the first part, let $O$ be the set of odd positive integers, and consider
$$
A = \inf\{i\in O: X_i \ne X_{i+1}\}.
$$

Comment: Possibly related: [Von Neumann's Coin Flip Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_coin)